# find the index of the first number that appears after a certain substring in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, .net-micro-framework

**Background Info**

I have a [fez panda II](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/256)  (that's running on **netmf 4.1**) in which is reading a load of bytes. These bytes are then being saved to an SD card in text format.

Currently, I'm saving the file as `1, 2, 3...`

However, I need these to be timestamped instead.

Since the Panda will loose power regularly, I can't use the on-board clock, nor can it use the `DateTime.Now` property.

The bytes being read also contain a *start time*.

The format of the string looks similar to:

```
c5@!c5dcSTART 11/01/2015          12:49:12
more data.... 124 xyz
more data...
some more data...
some even more numeric/text data...
more data which include the word "START"...
```

---

**The Goal**

Is there a way of retrieving this start time? It will have to be *pretty fast* too, since the data is being read at some speed, and the file handling thread is already lagging slightly.

The date would also need to be saved as a file name, so the forward slashes may need to be replaced with "file name safe" alternatives.

My overall Goal is to timestamp the files as they are saved.

*I'm thinking if I could get the first 12 digits after the first occurrence of `START` I **should** be able to work on from there.*

Anyone know how i could get the index of '1' after the word 'START'?

---

**Attempts To Date**

I have tried using the String.IndexOf, then a substring to contain the 'line', followed by a trim, although this seems *extremely* slow and will more than likely cause a lose of data.

I have also tried splitting the whole message into a char array (and going through to find the word "START", and then going through to get the 'numbers' after it), but this also seems to be very inefficient

---

**Updates**

I've very recently found out that I can't use regex as this was only implemented for NetMF 4.2+ whereas the Fez Panda runs on 4.1.

Comment: so is `START` the substring? And will it occur within the rest of the data too? Is there anything else that would be more descriptive?

Comment: Start appears multiple times unfortunately. I just know that the digits appear after the first occurrence.

Comment: @CoderDennis: using the likes of IndexOf().., splitting it into a char array and working from there. I'm just not great with writing the '**efficient**' code.

Comment: If the first `START` appears in a consistent position, using `Substring` with start index and length will be fastest.

Comment: @user1620220: It doesn't appear in a constant position i'm afriad, athough should always be the first word before this date and time

Comment: If you are noticing a big performance hit just reading the string, I suspect the string is very large and it may make sense to stream it instead. i.e. read only until you have found what you're looking for.

Comment: @user1620220: that'd be a great idea for most users. Only in this case, it's going to have to be read anyway and saved. (the message has been read at this point, just not saved). I was just trying to extract the date to save it as the file name (note. the forward slashes would also cause file name issues)

Comment: In that case it sounds like you won't do much better than what you mention as your second attempt. If that's not fast enough you will have to rethink things.

Comment: rethinking in progress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

executing on the first raw of data the following code, should produce desired values

```
 var splits = val.Split(new char[]{' ', '\t'}`)
 string date = splits[1];
 string time = splits[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
Regex r = new Regex("START\\s([\\d/]+)\\s+([\\d:])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(text);
if (m.Success) 
{
    string date = m.Groups[1].Value;  // this is the date portion
    string time = m.Groups[2].Value;  // this is the time portion
}
```

You could change the pattern to be more strict too:

```
(\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d\\d)\\s+(\\d\\d?:\\d\\d?:\\d\\d?)
```

Comment: unfortunately (being a regex virgin) I've just found out that the Panda II runs netMF 4.1 and so doesn't have regex. Regex was first implemented for NetMF in 4.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

use string.split("text") then get the second element of the array ( it is the part after the string you are looking for and use regex
like that :

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: unfortunately (being a regex virgin) I've just found out that the Panda II runs netMF 4.1 and so doesn't have regex. Regex was first implemented for NetMF in 4.2 :(

Comment: Make it the bad way then , use IndexOf for all the numbers 0-9 and then look for the smallest number you can do that using a for cycle and array. Mark as answered if you consider the question for answered

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an adaptation of @Tigran's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27906298/3436942) of splitting, and looked like:

```
var x = message.IndexOf("START")+5;
string time = message.Substring(x,35);
string [] test = time.Split(new char[]{'/',':'});
```

In which I could then access it via

```
test[0]+test[1]+test[2]+test[3]+test[4];
```

---

Once again, i admit this is by *far* probably the most inefficient way of solving this, ***so far***, at least, it seems to be able to cope ok-ish. (Although I will still accept Tigran's answer).